# How to make background images fully cover the page edge to edge in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to have a background image taking full height and full width of my document (which is set with all four margins equal to zero).

Annoyingly though, Google docs adds very small left and top margins to inserted images, with apparently no way to remove these (how disappointing of Google if there's no work around, you would expect such arbitrary limitation from Microsoft but not from them).

I cannot find a way to remove these blank spaces, so I can't have my image reach all edges of my page. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

Select the image.

In the bottom left corner of the image click 'inline text' and then 'wrap text'. Hopefully the box should go away.

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Select the image, then on the tool bar, click on Format -> Borders & Lines -> Border Color -> choose transparent or white color (the background color of your Google Slides)

Then the border of your image will disappear.

Comment: The question is about making background images extend to cover the complete page without any space around them not about removing a colored border.